# What could be causing my R dumbbell plot to only display a single point on the x-axis?

Tags: plot, graph, categorical-data

I am trying to create a dumbell plot of two categorical variables.

The data is participants in a study who have samples collected at certain timepoints in a study. Participants are labelled P-001, P-002 etc and have samples collected at BL, WK1, WK2, W3, Wk4 and D90 where that is also the order of timepoints. This is the code I used but I ended up with only a single point on the x-axis for timepoint and cannot seem to find a way to resolve having the x-axis as the timepoints I am after. Thanks in advance

#Define the desired order of the timepoint variable

```
desired_order \<- c("BL", "WK1", "WK2", "WK3", "WK4", "D90")
```

#Convert variable to a factor with desired order

```
datafram$timepoint \<- factor(datafram$timepoint , levels = desired_order)
```

#Create the plot

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = timepoint, y = participant)) +
geom_segment(aes(xend = timepoint', yend = participant), size = 1) +
geom_point(size = 3) +
labs(x = timepoint, y = participant) +
theme_minimal()
```

This is the graphical output
[output of the above code *note different participant values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP9RA.png)